# Some doubts regarding Hopf Rinow theorem

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am studying Riemannian Geometry in my own. And I was going through the proof of Hopf Rinow from the book of Carmo . I have a few doubts if one could help.

1. In one side it has been proved that if $exp_p$ is defined on all of $T_pM$ then there exists a length minimizing geodesics between $p$ and $q$. Since geodesics are locally length minimizing by definition, I am not clear how to get exactly the idea how far it minimizes.
2. In this direction of the proof which is essentially same in this pdf [https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~lee/Sven05.pdf](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Elee/Sven05.pdf)

**where we are exactly using the assumption that $exp_p$ is defined on all of $T_pM$?**

3. **Here in the proof we are taking $x_0=exp_p(\delta v)$ and I guess it's coming from the fact that every geodesics starting from $p$ in normal nbd of the from $ exp_p(sv)$ for some unit tangent vector in $T_pM$.**

However in Prop.5.11 of **Lee's** book in normal nbd geodesics from $p$ is given by $\gamma_V(t)=(tV^1,..,tV^n)$ .
So I am very much confused about what is exactly the expression of **geodesics starting from the point $p$ in normal neighborhoods .**

Any help would definitely help my understanding in the subject.

Comment: Your last question has not much to do with Hopf-Rinow theorem, I suggest you asked a separated question on that.

Comment: Ok sure. But can you please help me with the fisrt two ?

Answer (score 3):

For the Hopf-Rinow theorem, we want to find a distance minimizing geodesic $\gamma$ from $p$ to $q$. The idea is:

1. Start with a normal neighbourhood $exp_p(B_{\delta}(0))$ of $p$; in this neighbourhood the geodesics from $p$ are of the form $exp_p(sv)$ for some $v$ in $T_p(S)$ with $|v| = 1$ and $s < \delta$.
2. Find a point $x_0$ on the boundary of $exp_p(B_{\delta}(0))$ that minimizes $d(x, q)$ amongst all $x$ on the boundary of $exp_p(B_{\delta}(0))$. Then our desired $\gamma$ starts with the geodesic from $p$ to $x_0$.
3. Repeat this process from $x_0$ until we get to $q$. At each step, we prove that the geodesic segment added in fact coincides with $\gamma$.

Why do we need $exp_p$ to be defined on all of $T_p(S)$? Well, if our surface was not complete, then this process of extending $\gamma$ iteratively might terminate at a point where $\gamma$ is not defined. But since $\gamma$ is defined for all real numbers, we do not get a contradiction.